# How to change css dynamic by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i have a style on header empty like

```
<style> 
.cls{

}
</style>
```

I want to change it dynamic by click example to

```
<style> 
.cls{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family  : Arial, Verdana;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: yellow;       
}
</style>
```

Here is my code **http://jsfiddle.net/nyf7T/**

```
<script>
    function changeCSS () {
        var style = 'font-size: 15px;'
        +   'font-family  : Arial, Verdana;'
        +   'border: 1px solid blue ;'
        +   'background-color: yellow;'; 
        alert(style);
    }

</script>
<style> 
.cls{

}
</style>
<div>
    <table style="margin:5px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="cls">
               abcd
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

  <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS();">Setstyle</a>
```

How to do that thank.

Comment: If JQuery is allowed, you can use `addClass()` to add the style to your element.

Comment: Do you really want to modify CSS declarations or just the style of a particular element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have asked is to change a rule of a CSS class.

You need to use `CSSStyleSheet.insertRule` method to do this. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule)

You might also need to look at these

`document.styleSheets` for getting the style sheets used in the page.

`styleSheet.cssRules` for getting the cssRules in a particular style sheet.

`rule.selectorText` property -> Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule/selectorText)

In your case you need to try something like this (or a more refined version)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.cls {
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <table style="margin:5px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="cls"> abcd </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="changeCSS();">Setstyle</a> 
<script>
        function changeCSS () {
           var myStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];

        var style = '.cls { font-size: 15px;'
            +   'font-family  : Arial, Verdana;'
            +   'border: 1px solid blue;'
            +   'background-color: yellow; }'; 

        myStyleSheet.insertRule(style, 0);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the working version here http://jsfiddle.net/dK65G/1/

Comment: What real-world scenarios would require this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery css function:

here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/nyf7T/6/

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.changecss').click (function(){
       $('.cls').css({
       'font-size': '15px',
       'font-family'  : 'Arial, Verdana',
       'border': '1px solid blue',
       'background-color': 'yellow'
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below piece of jQuery

```
$('.cls').css({
    "font-size":"15px",
    "font-family":"Arial",
    "border":"1px solid blue",
    "background-color":"yellow"
});
```

cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use the below code

```
var style = '.cls{font-size: 15px;'
    +   'font-family  : Arial, Verdana;'
    +   'border: 1px solid blue;'
    +   'background-color: yellow;}'; 

document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML=style;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nyf7T/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code into a class.

And set the class to the element onclick:

```
    function changeCSS () {
        $( "element" ).addClass( "theclass" );
    }
```

In CSS:

```
.theclass {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family  : Arial, Verdana;
   border: 1px solid blue ;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

if you want to change the clicked element do this:

```
function changeCSS (this) {
    $(this).addClass( "theclass" );
}

<a href="#" onclick="changeCSS(this);">Setstyle</a>
```

The clou is to set up the CSS before you allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style> 
.cls{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family  : Arial, Verdana;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: yellow;       
}

.newCls {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family  : Arial, Verdana;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   background-color: yellow;
}
</style>


<a href="#" onclick="$(this).removeClass('cls').addClass('newCls');">Setstyle</a>
```